# zend-db not performing pdo bind replacements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, zend-db

My Zend Db Code is not performing the pdo bind replacements. You can see an output of my database:

```
mysql> select * from nzbsources;
+----+----------+-------+------------+-------+--------------+--------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+--------------+------------+------------+
| id | parentid | flags | categoryid | hash  | releaseName  | imdbId | srcLinkUri  | srcTitle  | rssUri  | pubdate | status | description  | created    | updated    |
+----+----------+-------+------------+-------+--------------+--------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+--------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |        0 |     0 |          0 | :hash | :releaseName |      0 | :srcLinkUri | :srcTitle | :rssUri |       0 |      1 | :description | 1518761515 | 1518761515 |
+----+----------+-------+------------+-------+--------------+--------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

Here is my project database connection config xml source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <database>
        <driver>Pdo_Mysql</driver>
        <database>nzbscraper</database>
        <username>root</username>
        <charset>utf8</charset>
        <platform>Mysql</platform>
    </database>
</root>
```

Here is my php code that handles the database querying

```
// load nzb database adapter
$dbConfigs=$projectConfigsArr['database'];
$dbConfigs['driver_options']=[
    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
];
$dbAdapter=new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($dbConfigs);
$qi = function ($name) use ($dbAdapter) {
    return $dbAdapter->platform->quoteIdentifier($name);
};
$fp = function ($name) use ($dbAdapter) {
    return $dbAdapter->driver->formatParameterName($name);
};

// insert nzb metadata into database
$dbTableName=$qi('nzbsources');
$sql="INSERT INTO $dbTableName (".$qi('hash').",".$qi('categoryid').",".$qi('releaseName').",".$qi('imdbId').",".$qi('srcLinkUri').",".$qi('srcTitle').",".$qi('rssUri').",".$qi('pubdate').",";
$sql.=$qi('status').",".$qi('description').",".$qi('created').",".$qi('updated').") VALUES ('".$fp('hash')."','".$fp('categoryid')."','".$fp('releaseName')."','";
$sql.=$fp('imdbId')."','".$fp('srcLinkUri')."','";
$sql.=$fp('srcTitle')."','".$fp('rssUri')."','".$fp('pubdate')."','1','".$fp('description')."',unix_timestamp(),unix_timestamp())";
$st=$dbAdapter->query($sql);
$params=[
   'hash'=>$nzbHash,
   'categoryid'=>$moviesHdCategoryId,
   'releaseName'=>$nzbReleaseName,
   'imdbId'=>$nzbImdbId,
   'srcLinkUri'=>$nzbLink,
   'srcTitle'=>$nzbEntryTitleRaw,
   'rssUri'=>$rssLink,
   'pubdate'=>$nzbPublishedDateUnixTimestamp,
   'description'=>$nzbEntryDescriptionRaw
];
$st->execute($params);
```

And here is my current mysql schema:

```
DROP TABLE `nzbsources`;
CREATE TABLE `nzbsources` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `flags` int(5) DEFAULT '0',
  `categoryid` int(11) not null default 0,
  `hash` varchar(255) not null default '',  
  `releaseName` varchar(255) not null default '',
  `imdbId` int(11) not null default 0,
  `srcLinkUri` varchar(255) not null default '',
  `srcTitle` varchar(255) not null default '',
  `rssUri` varchar(255) not null default '',
  `pubdate` int(11) not null default 0,
  `status` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `description` text,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_parent` (`id`,`parentid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hash` (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE `nzbcategories`;
CREATE TABLE `nzbcategories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `flags` int(5) DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) not null default '',
  `status` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `description` text,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_parent` (`id`,`parentid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: did my answer helped you to resolve your issue or you still having the some issues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with how $sql is created, it seems to be missing ':' for bind param to work.

For e.g. The insert query should look like below, where values need to have ':' in front of them.

```
INSERT INTO USER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES (:FIRST_NAME, :LAST_NAME);
```

Your $params value are correctly added.

```
$params = array(
    'FIRST_NAME' => 'John',
    'LAST_NAME' => 'Smith'
);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think the $fp anonymous function is already doing that. I think the issue is i dont have the semi colons inside the binds array. ill keep you updated.

Comment: @jkushner In my code it works without using colon in the bind array. Can you please print $sql and paste it here?

Comment: also worth trying to just put bind param :hash manually without it passing through your function to see if it stores the data